# find complement of regular expression

Tags: regex, complement

There's a question on my exercise sheet to find the complement of  two formulas

(1) `(aa|bb)*`

and

(2) `(a|b)(aa|bb)(a|b)`.

complement of both is in my opinion `a* | b*`, meaning only `a`'s or only `b`'s?

Comment: related: [A regular expression for the complement of the language L](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9861949/1048572)

Comment: also: [How do I turn any regex into a complement of itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977455/how-do-i-turn-any-regex-into-an-complement-of-itself-without-complex-hand-editin)

Comment: In short: No. `aba` for example is neither matched by the formulas nor by your solution, so it can't be the complement.

Answer (score 6):

You need to go through the usual procedure:

- Convert regex to NFA.
- Convert NFA to DFA. For simple case, it is easy to convert (by hand) from regex to DFA directly.
- Turn all non-terminal state into terminal states and vice versa.
- Convert the complementing DFA to regex. [This is one detailed example of such conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676431/regular-expressions-with-repeated-characters/13677120#13677120)

I won't show you the result since it is exercise, but I will show you the DFA for the first formula `(aa|bb)*`:

[image: Formula 1]

From this, you can see clearly that `a*` or `b*` will not give the correct result. You will never end up in the ***Trap*** state (which becomes a terminal state in the complementing regular expression), and you may end up in state ***2a/2b*** (which becomes **non**-terminal state in the complementing regular expression).

Comment: What did you use to make this graph?

Answer (score 0):

Simply (aa+bb)* will contain sample strings such as null, aa, aaaa, bb, bbbb, aabb, bbaa, and so on observe that all strings that can be formed are of even length and a and b can be any order, so complement should contain all odd-length strings ((a+b)(a+b))*(a+b)